# For loop array with multiple variables using numeric value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a for loop in an array, to make it display the random numbers in sort order (High to lower) when a button is clicked on within the html plus time the action, I have done this and it works by displaying the results with each number on a new line from 100 to 1 and giving the time in milliseconds.

What I'm trying to do, is make it display 10 numbers per line, but not sure how to go about it.

**Javascript**

```
function Numberordermatch() {

    var start = new Date().getTime();

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {

    var points = [77, 57, 18, 35, 36, 33, 43, 87, 100, 14, 73, 97, 96, 27, 34, 39, 23, 71, 1, 86, 56, 21, 26, 65, 20, 29, 55, 49, 16, 42, 90, 91, 59, 84, 38, 75, 82, 66, 17, 62, 30, 63, 74, 89, 22, 50, 68, 31, 78, 81, 44, 93, 9, 40, 41, 48, 19, 32, 46, 28, 53, 70, 52, 60, 80, 47, 15, 069, 7, 67, 13, 61, 5, 94, 6, 98, 99, 83, 76, 88, 25, 72, 79, 37, 51, 64, 8, 2, 92, 12, 54, 045, 3, 58, 11, 95, 24, 10, 85, 4];

    points.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;

}

    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;

    text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        text += points[i] + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =
    ('<strong>This function took: ' + time + 'ms to load</strong>');

}
```

Comment: `text += points[i] + ((i % 10 === 0) ? '<br />' : '');`

Comment: definitely a time to use modulo

Comment: love modulo, love ternary

Comment: `var points = ...` don't need to be in the loop neither does `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Ian Brindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698723/ian-brindley) answer it could be :

```
var text = '';
var points = [77, 57, 18, 35, 36, 33, 43, 87, 100, ...]
points.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    text += points[i] + ", " + ((i % 10 === 0) ? '<br />' : '');
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Thank you this is helpful to me, one quick question. How do I get the "," to display between each number. As it is now like this when the sort is displayed.

100
99989796959493929190
89888786858483828180
79787776757473727170
69686766656463626160
59585756555453525150
49484746444342414039
38373736353433323130
29282726252423222120
19181716151413121110
987654321

Comment: I have modified my answer to have a "," between numbers. You should accept the answer if it answers your question so that it can help people with the same issue : )